# SELECT command with a WHERE condition and an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, inner-join, where-clause

I'm sure I must be making a trivial mistake here, but I've been searching around for help with this problem and all I can find is information on conditional INNER JOINs.

**< EDIT >** The problem is that this stored procedure is not returning anything at all. If I type just:

```
SELECT TOP (6) UserID, Category, Title, SUBSTRING(Article, 0, 200) AS Summary, DatePosted
FROM ContribContent
WHERE (DateFeatured IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY DateFeatured DESC
```

Into the console then I get values returned. So it must be something to do with the inner-join? **< / EDIT >**

The idea is to:

1. take the content which has been
   featured (DateFeatured is NOT NULL)
   and place it all into a temporary
   table
2. get the user names and picture from the users table and match them to the values in the     temporary table using the UserID value.
3. sort the temporary table in order of the date each post was featured.
4. select the top six entries from the table

Here's the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[admin_GetFeaturedContrib]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FeaturedContrib TABLE (
 UserID INT,
 Category INT,
 Title varchar(100),
 Summary varchar(200),
 DatePosted date,
 FirstName varchar(50),
 LastName varchar(50),
 Picture varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @FeaturedContrib
SELECT TOP 6 ContribContent.UserID, ContribContent.Category, ContribContent.Title,     SUBSTRING(ContribContent.Article, 0, 200) AS Summary, ContribContent.DatePosted,     Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Picture
FROM ContribContent
INNER JOIN Users
ON ContribContent.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE ContribContent.DateFeatured IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ContribContent.DateFeatured DESC

SELECT * FROM @FeaturedContrib
END
```

There are two data tables involved:

**Users** - a table storing all of the users and their information.

- UserID INT
- FirstName varchar(50)
- LastName varchar(50)
- Picture varchar(50)
- etc...

**ContribContent**

- ContribContentID INT
- UserID INT
- Category INT
- Title varchar(100)
- Article  varchar(MAX)
- Picture  varchar(50)
- DatePosted date
- DateFeatured date
- Deleted bit

**THANKS** to anyone who can help out!

Comment: Wow that was stupid of me.. Sorry aha, just made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run only -

```
SELECT TOP 6 ContribContent.UserID, ContribContent.Category, ContribContent.Title,     SUBSTRING(ContribContent.Article, 0, 200) AS Summary, ContribContent.DatePosted,     Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Picture
FROM ContribContent
INNER JOIN Users
ON ContribContent.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE ContribContent.DateFeatured IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ContribContent.DateFeatured DESC
```

See what you getting might be an issue with your `Where` or your `join` see carefully if you have any data in the first place being returned. My guess is `join` see if you have matching userids you are joining on...(**Hint** : Left join maybe your answer)

Comment: No there's no data returned. I just wrote a quick edit in response to Bannister's comment. If you check out the code in the edit, that code is returning values. So is it something wrong with the inner-join then?

Comment: Hah perfect, left join worked, but was returning nulls for the joined columns. I decided to check the Users table and found out the UserIDs start at 5 for some reason. The only content which had been featured had a UserID value of 2. I feel bad that it was such a stupid mistake. I'm taking over this site from another developer so I wasn't aware. Thanks so much.

Comment: Also,Probably want to use `Isnull(ContribContent.UserID,0) as UserId` and assign a value(`0` i have in this case) suitable to your needs.Glad I could help!